# I am creating bar button in all classes .is there any way to create the bar button only one time and use it in all classes?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am creating a `bar button` in all classes. Is there anyway *to write this code only once* and be used in all classes?

```
 toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, 100, 45)];
    toolbar.tintColor=self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;

    // create an array for the buttons
    NSMutableArray* buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    // create a standard save button

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];

    UIButton *homeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [homeButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    homeButton.frame = CGRectMake(100,2, 35, 35);

    [homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(homeButtonpress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *customHomeBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:homeButton];

    [buttonsArray addObject:customHomeBarItem];
    [customHomeBarItem release];


    UIImage *logoutImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"power.png"];

    UIButton *logOutBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [logOutBtn setImage:logoutImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [logOutBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(logOutButtonPress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    logOutBtn.frame=CGRectMake(0, 2, 35, 40);


    UIBarButtonItem *customLogOutButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:logOutBtn];

    [buttonsArray addObject:customLogOutButton];
    [customLogOutButton release];


    [toolbar setItems:buttonsArray animated:NO];
    [buttonsArray release];

    // place the toolbar into the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Create a Utility class
> 2. Add class method for creating & returning UIBarButtonItem.
> 3. Import Utility.h in .pch or in classes where you want to use it.

**Utility.m**

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *) barButtonItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title backgroundImage:(NSString *)image target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    //create button & return it
    return barButtonItem;
}
```

To use

**ViewController.m**

```
    UIBarButtonItem* backButtonItem = [Utility barButtonItemWithTitle:@" Back" backgroundImage:@"back_button" target:self action:@selector(backButtonAction)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

Comment: How to call this method from this class in which i have to use it?

Comment: +1. Good answer. You could also do this via a class category, which I'd likely do instead in lieu of having to create a utility class, perhaps.

Comment: Please let me know how to do it via category class . it would be pleasure for me...

Comment: Go through below tutorial for creating categories. You will find more if you google. http://iphone-obsessed.blogspot.in/2010/05/tutorial-creating-class-categories-in.html